# How to create this sort of gritty, badly scanned texture?

Tags: texture

How can I recreate the texture below? I always adored these collaged paperized 'gritty, badly scanned' grainy almost fabric-ky effect on a pic.

[image]

Comment: Hi there and welcome to GDSE. It would be really helpful if you specified which application you use.

Comment: @Wolff it would be "mega" helpful!

Comment: Appears to be "halftones" in Photoshop. Search this on YouTube :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears to be a scan of a colour halftone image. These are commonly seen in newspapers, if you examine them closely enough.

Photoshop and GIMP have filters that can apply such an effect.

In Photoshop: *Filter > Pixelate > Color Halftone*

In GIMP: *Filters > Distorts > Newsprint*

Comment: thank you so much!! you nailed it that's exactly it!!

Comment: @RafReyes, unless you are waiting for better answers to come up, please remember to *accept* the answer so other can benefit from it and Billy can get some more of his precious reputation points.